# Rational Function definition (Hartshorne)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be varieties. A rational map $\phi: X \to Y$ is an equivalence of pairs $(U, \phi_U)$ where $U$ is a nonempty open subset of $X$, and $\phi_U$ is a morphism of $U$ to $Y$, and where $(U, \phi_U)$ and $(V, \phi_V)$ are considered equivalent if $\phi_U$ and $\phi_V$ agree on $U \cap V$.

I can't convince myself of the following statement: The rational map $\phi$ is dominants if for some and hence for every pair $(U, \phi_U)$ the image of $\phi_U$ is dense in $Y$.

1. Does Hartshorne mean every pair in the equivalence class? However, even then I can't see why $\phi_U$ having dense image implies that $\phi_V$ will? This would makes sense if both $U$ and $V$ were varieties, in which case two morphism agreeing on the intersection implies agreement everywhere, but $U$ and $V$ are not necessarily varieties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point here is that if a rational map $\phi: X \to Y$ has a dense image, then for any open subset $V \subset X$, the image $\phi(V)$ will already be dense, so this is also true for any of the $(U, \phi_U)$.

Answer (score 0):

I am late but for the record it may be still useful to write my answer.

By *variety* I mean any affine variety, projective variety, quasi-affine variety or quasi-projective variety. We start with the case of an irreducible variety $X$, namely an affine variety or a projective variety, in a second step we will reduce the case where the variety $X$ is not assumed to be irreducible (namely quasi-affine or quasi-projective variety) to the irreducible case.

Asume $X$ is irreducible and let $(U,\phi_U)$,$(V,\phi_V)$ be two representatives of $\phi:X\to Y$ and assume that $\text{Im}\phi_U$ dense.

$\bullet$ Since $U, V$ are open and they are not empty sets then their complements $X-U, X-V$ are closed proper subsets of $X$. Hence, if $U\cap V$ is empty then $X=X-(U\cap V)=(X-U)\cup (X-V)$. But $X$ is irreducible, so $U\cap V$ is not empty.

$\bullet$ Now we want to prove that $cl_X(U\cap V) = X$, where $cl_X$ denotes the closure in $X$. Since $X$ is irreducible, $U\cap V$ is not empty and one has $X=cl_X(U\cap V) \cup (X-(U\cap V))$, one concludes $cl_X(U\cap V) = X$.

$\bullet$ Moreover, one has $cl_U(U\cap V) = cl_X(U\cap V) \cap U$.

$\bullet$ The two previous points combine to give $cl_U(U\cap V) = U$.

$\bullet$ Since $\phi_U$ is a continuous morphism one has $cl_Y(\phi_U(cl_U(U\cap V)))\subseteq cl_Y(\phi_U(U\cap V))$.

$\bullet$ With the last point and remembering that $cl_U(U\cap V) = U$, one has $Y = cl_Y(\phi_U(U)) = cl_Y(\phi_U(cl_U(U\cap V))) \subseteq cl_Y(\phi_U(U\cap V)) = cl_Y(\phi_V(U\cap V)) \subseteq cl_Y(\phi_V(V))$.
Thus $\text{Im}\phi_V$ is dense.

Assume that $X$ is only a quasi-variety (quasi-affine or quasi-projective). In this case $X$ is an open subset of an irreducible variety $X'$, and $U = X\cap U'$, $V=X\cap V'$, for some non-empty open subsets of $X'$. By a double application of the previous argument in the irreducible case, one concludes successively that $U'\cap V'$ is not empty, and (assuming without lost of generality that X is a non-empty open subset of $X'$) $X\cap (U'\cap V')$ is not empty. But  $X\cap (U'\cap V') = (X\cap U')\cap (X\cap V') = U\cap V$. So $U\cap V$ is a non-empty subset of $X'$, now we can plug this fact in the irreducible case since $X'$ is irreducible to prove that $\text{Im}\phi_V$ is dense if $\text{Im}\phi_U$ is.